# How is opencl getInfo implemented

Tags: c++, opencl

I am new to OpenCL programming and interest in the implementation of `getInfo` function. As you may know, the return type of this function depends on what information you are requesting. For example, `device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()` will give you a `string`, `device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_TYPE>()` will give you a `cl_device_type` value and `device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_AVAILABLE>()` will give you a `bool`. I wonder how is it implemented in C++? I know the actual return type of this function is `detail::param_traits< detail::cl_device_info, name >::param_type`, but how is that converted into an actual return type like `string`?

Thank you very much

Comment: . o O ( How do the Heisenberg Compensators work? - They work just fine, thank you. )

Comment: You can examine the implementation in [cl2.hpp](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/cl2_8hpp_source.html)